# PSQL: How to extract information and collect all values in a specific column successfully

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling with a scenario where I have multiple rows repeating the same information except for one of their columns:

```
  {
    "common_name": "www.leagueoflegends.com",
    "issuer_name": "C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3",
    "not_before": "2016-03-24T00:00:00",
    "not_after": "2017-03-24T23:59:59",
    "key_algorithm": "RSA",
    "key_size": 2048,
    "serial_number": "\\x5cbeb7904e749cd466f1167bcd922ef0",
    "signature_hash_algorithm": "SHA-256",
    "signature_key_algorithm": "RSA",
    "subject_name": "C=US, ST=California, L=Los Angeles, O=\"Riot Games, Inc.\", CN=www.leagueoflegends.com",
    "name": "\\x3075310b3009060355040613025553311330110603550408130a43616c69666f726e6961311430120603550407140b4c6f7320416e67656c657331193017060355040a141052696f742047616d65732c20496e632e3120301e060355040314177777772e6c65616775656f666c6567656e64732e636f6d",
    "alt_names": "bertha.leagueoflegends.com"
  },
  {
    "common_name": "www.leagueoflegends.com",
    "issuer_name": "C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3",
    "not_before": "2016-03-24T00:00:00",
    "not_after": "2017-03-24T23:59:59",
    "key_algorithm": "RSA",
    "key_size": 2048,
    "serial_number": "\\x5cbeb7904e749cd466f1167bcd922ef0",
    "signature_hash_algorithm": "SHA-256",
    "signature_key_algorithm": "RSA",
    "subject_name": "C=US, ST=California, L=Los Angeles, O=\"Riot Games, Inc.\", CN=www.leagueoflegends.com",
    "name": "\\x3075310b3009060355040613025553311330110603550408130a43616c69666f726e6961311430120603550407140b4c6f7320416e67656c657331193017060355040a141052696f742047616d65732c20496e632e3120301e060355040314177777772e6c65616775656f666c6567656e64732e636f6d",
    "alt_names": "battlegrounds.ru.leagueoflegends.com"
  },
```

As you can see, the only field that returns something different is `alt_names`.

I was wondering if could be possible to get all the `alt_names` value in an array and then return a single row with the remaining columns, appending the array for `alt_names`.

Eventually I would like to format the query output as a JSON, as follows:

```
[
  {
    "common_name": "www.leagueoflegends.com",
    "issuer_name": "C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3",
    "not_before": "2016-03-24T00:00:00",
    "not_after": "2017-03-24T23:59:59",
    "key_algorithm": "RSA",
    "key_size": 2048,
    "serial_number": "\\x5cbeb7904e749cd466f1167bcd922ef0",
    "signature_hash_algorithm": "SHA-256",
    "signature_key_algorithm": "RSA",
    "subject_name": "C=US, ST=California, L=Los Angeles, O=\"Riot Games, Inc.\", CN=www.leagueoflegends.com",
    "name": "\\x3075310b3009060355040613025553311330110603550408130a43616c69666f726e6961311430120603550407140b4c6f7320416e67656c657331193017060355040a141052696f742047616d65732c20496e632e3120301e060355040314177777772e6c65616775656f666c6567656e64732e636f6d",
    "alt_names": "www.leagueoflegends.com", "xxx", "yyy", "zzz", ...
  }
]
```

Could someone please assist me here?

**EDIT**: Adding more information:

This is how my query currently looks like:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
            FROM(
                SELECT
                    x509_commonName(c.certificate) as common_name,
                    x509_issuerName(c.certificate) as issuer_name,
                    x509_notBefore(c.certificate) as not_before,
                    x509_notAfter(c.certificate) as not_after,
                    x509_keyAlgorithm(c.certificate) as key_algorithm,
                    x509_keySize(c.certificate) as key_size,
                    x509_serialNumber(c.certificate) as serial_number,
                    x509_signatureHashAlgorithm(c.certificate) as signature_hash_algorithm,
                    x509_signatureKeyAlgorithm(c.certificate) as signature_key_algorithm,
                    x509_subjectName(c.certificate) as subject_name,
                    x509_name(c.certificate) as name,
                    x509_altNames(c.certificate) as alt_names
        FROM certificate c
                WHERE c.id = '$1') t
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use `array_agg` with results returned from functions, hence why I'm looking for another alternative.

Also, I'm not expecting to store this into another column, instead I just want to receive the output in JSON and process it through a script on python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving this problem as follows:

```
SELECT row_to_json(u)
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                x509_commonName(c.certificate),
                x509_issuerName(c.certificate) as issuer_name,
                x509_notBefore(c.certificate) as not_before,
                x509_notAfter(c.certificate) as not_after,
                x509_keyAlgorithm(c.certificate) as key_algorithm,
                x509_keySize(c.certificate) as key_size,
                x509_serialNumber(c.certificate) as serial_number,
                x509_signatureHashAlgorithm(c.certificate) as signature_hash_algorithm,
                x509_signatureKeyAlgorithm(c.certificate) as signature_key_algorithm,
                x509_subjectName(c.certificate) as subject_name,
                x509_name(c.certificate) as name,
                (
                    SELECT array_to_json(ARRAY(SELECT x509_altNames(c.certificate)
                    FROM certificate c
                    WHERE c.id = '$1'))
                )
            FROM certificate c
            WHERE c.id = '$1'
        ) u
```